# Output mysql results using checkbox and search bar using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code. but the problem is it only display the results based from the last checked checkbox. I want to display results when two or more checkbox is checked. I dont know what's missing. I filter the results when the submit button is clicked.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A'";

if(isset($_POST['filter'])){

  $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['location']);

  if(empty($_POST['price'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A' AND location LIKE  '%".$location."%'";

  }else{

    foreach($_POST['price'] as $price){


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A' AND location LIKE  '%".$location."%' AND price IN ('$price')";

    }
  }
}

$query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

This is the html that I created for it. I didnt include on how the results is displayed. I find it irrelevant to the question.

```html
<form name="location form" method="POST"">
  Filter by Location: <input type="text" name="location" placeholder=" " value=""/><br><br>
  <label><strong>Price Range:</strong></label>
  <br>
  <input  class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="s 500 - s 1000">$500-$1000<br>
  <input  class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="s 2500 - s 4000">$2500-$4000<br>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="s 5000 - s 9000">$5000-$9000<br>
  <input  class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="s 10000 - s 50000">$10000-$50000<br>
<input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" >
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly be appreciated and have a nice day!

Update
when I check all the checkbox this is the output when I echo it
s 500 - s 1000s 2500 - s 4000s 5000 - s 9000s 10000 - s 50000

Comment: `foreach($_POST['price'] as $key => $price){`

Comment: @sietse85 is it okay if you kindly elaborate? I still put $price in query?

Comment: yes, that is the actual price

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: @sietse85 didnt work. :( I tried to output $price when I checked $500-$1000 and $5000-$9000. output = '$500-$1000$5000-$9000'

Comment: @Jens it would be helpful if you posted a link towards a tutorial or something, i see so much people ramble this line over and over without providing any additional info

Comment: @RagnaRok what datatype is price in your database? If you left the dollar sign out of the value you could do something like `$p = explode('-', $price) $min = $p[0] $max = $p[1] `AND rewrite your query where with `WHERE price > $min AND price < $max`

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove it. in my database its varchar since the values must be etc (s 500 - s 1000). that was the instructions. I tried exploding it. but it returns mysql errors

Comment: @sietse85 Toutorials can be found using Google.

Comment: seems like the `$sql` variable gets overwritten and only the last value in the array gets to be thrown inside the query.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi how do I resolve this? Sorry Im still a newbie to php

Comment: you need to execute the query within the `foreach()` loop before `foreach()` moves to the next price value, then once you execute the query and fetch results, store inside an array, then once `foreach()` is completed, you should have the final array as expected

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I apologize, I cant quite follow. I should put this query $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A' AND location LIKE  '%".$location."%' AND price IN ('$price')"; before the foreach? really sorry

Comment: @Jens also bad tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I wrapped the element in quotes first then implode it on my query. thank you for all the help guys.

```
$finalprice = array(); 
foreach($_POST['price'] as $key=>$price){
    $finalprice[] = "'" . $price . "'"; 
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A' AND location LIKE  '%".$location."%' AND price IN (".implode(',',$finalprice).")";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this ;)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A'";

if(isset($_POST['filter'])){

  $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['location']);

  if(empty($_POST['price'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type ='A' AND location LIKE  '%".$location."%'";

  }else{

    foreach($_POST['price'] as $price){

      if($price == 500){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'A' AND location LIKE  '%".$location."%' AND price >= '".$price."' AND price = '".$price."' AND price = '".$price."' AND price = '".$price."' AND price
```

```
<form name="location form" method="POST"">
  Filter by Location: <input type="text" name="location" placeholder=" " value=""/><br><br>
  <label><strong>Price Range:</strong></label>
  <br>
  <input  class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="500">$500-$1000<br>
  <input  class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="2500">$2500-$4000<br>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="5000">$5000-$9000<br>
  <input  class="form-check-input" name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="10000">$10000-$50000<br>
<input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" >
</form>
```

Comment: A good answer includes a proper explanation about _why_ the OP should use your code. What problem is it solving and how? Don't let people guess. Also, what's the link about? Is it some self promotion?